# Twig Wordpress Repeater within a repeater

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber, nested-repeater

I would like to ask for help regarding a repeater within a repeater on Wordpress using Twig. The Services section shows up correctly but the Features section within the Services section isn't showing up.

Here is a screenshot of the Wordpress ACF.[Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6D3U.png)

And right below is the code that I am currently using.
Please advise. Thank you!

```
{% extends "page.twig" %}
{% block additional %}

<div id="page-services">
  <section id="services">  
    <div class="row small-up-1 large-up-1">
    <div class="small-12 medium-11 large-9 columns small-centered">
    <div class="services-grid animated fadeIn wow">
    <p align="center">
      {{post.services_desc}}
    </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="line centered"></div>
</div>

<center>
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 medium-11 large-9 columns small-centered">
<div class="features-header animated fadeIn wow">

{% for item in post.get_field('services_ist') %}

  <div class="column services">
    <h2 class="capitalize bold">
      {{item.services_title}}
    </h2>

  {% if item.services_subtitle %}
    <h4 class="subtitle">
      {{item.services_subtitle}}
    </h4>

<div class="line thin"></div>

  {% endif %}

  {% if item.services_content %}
    <div class="description">
      {{item.services_content}}
      <br><br>
    </div>
  {% endif %}

{% if feats.services_feat %}
  {% for feats in post.get_field('services_feat') %}
    <p>{{feats.feat_title}}</p>
  {% endfor %}


  {% if feats.feats_desc %}
    <h4 class="feats description">
      {{feats.feats_desc}}
    </h4>
  {% endif %}

{% endif %}

  </div>
{% endfor %}
</center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  </section>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [ACF Integration Guide](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/#nested-repeater-fields) says, you shouldn’t use `get_field()` again when you try to access nested repeater fields:

> When you run get_field on an outer ACF field, everything inside is ready to be traversed. You can refer to nested fields via item_outer.inner_repeater

So instead of using:

```
{% for feats in post.get_field('services_feat') %}
```

You should use:

```
{% if feats.services_feat %}
    {% for feats in feats.services_feat %}
        <p>{{ feats.feat_title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    {# … #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never done twig before but a quick search got me something.
Change the inner repeater to this:

```
  {% for feats in services_ist.get_field('services_feat') %}
    <p>{{feats.feat_title}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

This way the second repeater knows that its a child from the first repeater instead of a direct child to the post.

Comment: Just tried this but it still doesn't work.
Thank you for trying though.